# Calculate the longest continuous running time of a device

Tags: iot, dolphindb, segment

I have a table created with the following script:

```
n=15 
ts=now()+1..n * 1000 * 100
status=rand(0 1 ,n) 
val=rand(100,n) 
t=table(ts,status,val) 
select * from t order by ts
```

where

*ts* is the time, *status* indicates the device status (0: down; 1: running), and *val* indicates the running time.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
ts  status  val
2023.01.03T18:17:17.386 1   58
2023.01.03T18:18:57.386 0   93
2023.01.03T18:20:37.386 0   24
2023.01.03T18:22:17.386 1   87
2023.01.03T18:23:57.386 0   85
2023.01.03T18:25:37.386 1   9
2023.01.03T18:27:17.386 1   46
2023.01.03T18:28:57.386 1   3
2023.01.03T18:30:37.386 0   65
2023.01.03T18:32:17.386 1   66
2023.01.03T18:33:57.386 0   56
2023.01.03T18:35:37.386 0   42
2023.01.03T18:37:17.386 1   82
2023.01.03T18:38:57.386 1   95
2023.01.03T18:40:37.386 0   19
```

So how do I calculate the longest continuous running time? For example, both the 7th and 8th records have the *status* 1, I want to sum their *val* values. Or the 14th-15th records, I want to sum up their *val* values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [segment](https://dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/s/segment.html) to group the consecutive identical values. The full script is as follows:

```
select first(ts), sum(iif(status==1, val, 0)) as total_val
from t 
group by segment(status)
having sum(iif(status==1, val, 0)) > 0
```

The result:

```
segment_status  first_ts    total_val
0   2023.01.03T18:17:17.386 58
3   2023.01.03T18:22:17.386 87
5   2023.01.03T18:25:37.386 58
9   2023.01.03T18:32:17.386 66
12  2023.01.03T18:37:17.386 177
```